# Using ASN.1 public key in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, ssl, asn.1

I am trying to communicate with a web service. In order to do that, I need to encrypt a message using the public key that I received from the web service. The doc says the following about the public key format:

*Format: X.509 encoded key in ANS.1 (sic!)*

(ANS.1 is ASN.1 I guess).
The public key is:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQDE+ApyETIF1cXzKnU144P6lg/FcilmuQS2wBvaWp6t9OovthGmrsszd7eo4rL6Nitj1YOKETTtnwm4T+1EEyBrgwcfXAlm3FasTC/HIzhRRa+F8Yuz+UZkGvgP8Qa6B0vRob2BjhWx1PfwuWHQxGvAjiqUJ/dEMjocFuCrY5NZqwIDAQAB-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

I tried to use this is a NodeJS code with the following:

```
const key = crypto.createPublicKey({
    key: Buffer.from(publicKey),
    format: 'der',
    type: 'pkcs1'
});
```

But I received the following error:

```
node:internal/crypto/keys:607
    handle.init(kKeyTypePublic, data, format, type, passphrase);
           ^

Error: error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_check_tlen:wrong tag
    at Object.createPublicKey (node:internal/crypto/keys:607:12)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/XXXXXXXX/wsClient.js:16:20)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1149:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1203:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1027:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:868:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47 {
  opensslErrorStack: [
    'error:0D09B00D:asn1 encoding routines:d2i_PublicKey:ASN1 lib',
    'error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_item_embed_d2i:nested asn1 error'
  ],
  library: 'asn1 encoding routines',
  function: 'asn1_check_tlen',
  reason: 'wrong tag',
  code: 'ERR_OSSL_ASN1_WRONG_TAG'
}
```

I can't even convert this public key using openssl into any usable format. The only way to see inside it for me was to use the following online tool:
https://lapo.it/asn1js/

Here I can at least see that the public key is valid, but I don't know how to use it in NodeJS. Converting it is also an accaptable solution for me.

Answer (score 1):

After some painful hours it turns out that two things had to be done:

1. replace "BEGIN CERTIFICATE" with "BEGIN PUBLIC KEY" and the same for the end
2. They also needed to be in a separate line

After that NodeJS Crypto is able to parse the key.
Interestingly phpseclib was able to parse the key in the original format and then output it in the correct one, that's how I realized the solution.